# Python in terminal

Tags: python, macos, terminal

This question concerns running python files in terminal that are not stored in the home directory. I think I have solved the first bit of this puzzle by modifying my path so that it includes the directory where my python programs are stored.

So where as initially 
`echo $PATH` would yield the following: `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

it now yields:
`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python`

However despite the fact that the correct folder is now in my path, none of the python files within this folder run. For example there is a file in there called recap.py, when I open terminal and type in: 
`python recap.py`
I get:

```
python: can't open file 'recap.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

If I simply type in `recap.py` (i.e. omitting the 'python' bit), I get:
`-bash: /Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python/recap.py: Permission denied`

Can anyone enlighten me? Ideally I want to set it up so as soon as terminal opens all I need to do is type the file name and not even type python.

I've spent hours trying to sort this out, any help is appreciated.

Paul.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Including the directory where a command lives in your $PATH means you can run commands in that directory from anywhere.  But in your first example, you are running the command "python" with recap.py as an argument.  So your shell does not search your $PATH to find where recap.py lives.  To make recap.py runnable as a command by itself, see this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

In short, you need to include `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line, and chmod the file to be executable (`chmod u+x recap.py`).

Answer (score 3):

You may have tried this before, but I ran into similar problems at one point and this is the process that works for me. In the directory where recap.py is stored:

```
chmod +x recap.py
./recap.py
```

The ./ being the key part, as it works as the full path to the directory. This also assumes that you have

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

or something similar as the first line of your program. The first two characters first line is called a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) and indicates that the file is a script to be executed by the interpreter specified by the path following it. So, as others have suggested, your python interpreter may be located somewhere other than /usr/bin (possibly in /bin), so you'll need to find this, and include this line at the top of any python script you wish to execute from the terminal.

If you don't know where python is located, you can use:

```
which python
```

at the terminal, which should print the path to your python install. You can then use that path after your shebang.

Comment: Hi, pretty sure python is in /usr/bin. Macbook is less than two weeks old, and when I type: ls -l /usr/bin into terminal I get a whole load of files, including python ones. I've tried both suggestions but still getting the same error message:

/Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python/recap.py: line 1: #!/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory
/Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python/recap.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python/recap.py: line 3: `start_num = int(raw_input("What number do you wish to start counting at?"))'

Comment: ./recap.py simply results in a file not found message

Comment: ./recap.py should not result in a file not found message if you have a file named "recap.py" in the directory which you're working. (type pwd to see your working directory, and ls to see its contents) To see if /usr/bin is the correct directory, there should be a file named 'env' and one named 'python'. I think on a mac python might be installed in /usr/local/bin/python

Comment: to find out for sure where python is installed type 'which python' into your terminal and use that after your shebang.

Comment: Checked /usr/bin and there is indeed a file named 'python' and one named 'env'. 'Which python' yields '/usr/bin/python'. So that seems to be as it should be. Unfortunately still no dice. I'm not sure what you mean by the directory in which I'm working. If i put the file in the directory 'paulpatterson' it works fine. What I want to do is put the file (and all subsequent python files) in a directory further downstream i.e. paulpatterson/Documents/Python.

Comment: So, mini lesson: When you're working at the terminal, at any given moment, you have a "working directory" you can find out what this is by typing pwd (for "print working directory"). The reason this works when the file is in paulpatterson is that it is most likely the directory you're working in (as it's probably your default working directory). If you want these steps to work with the file in a directory downstream, you're going to have to move to that directory using the cd command.

Comment: So, 'pwd' shows you're in '/Users/paulpatterson', then you're going to need to use the command 'cd Documents/Python'. Then, when you use 'pwd' it should show '/Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python'. If you then type 'ls' it should show you the files in that directory. If recap.py is one of them, './recap.py' will run it.

Comment: Seriously though, spend an hour on that website Daenyth suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the first line in every script is "#!/usr/bin/env python" (no qoutes). Do "chmod +x file.py" for every file.  You should then be able to run each script as file.py.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. Have added suggested line to top of file, but when I try the chmod thing I get:

chmod: recap.py: No such file or directory

So still can't get script to run

Comment: If you ran `chmod +x file.py`, then `file.py` needs to be in your current working directory or you need to specify the full path to the file.  chmod isn't going to search your entire filesystem for a random file.py and chmod it.

Comment: @Paul Patterson, you need change to the directory containing file.py or give the full path to chmod. "cd /Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python/" first, or do "chmod +x /Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python/file.py"

Comment: Okay, i've specified the full path using:  chmod u+x /Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python/recap.py.
File is now found, but doesn't execute properly; terminal displays the following:  

/Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python/recap.py: line 1: #!/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory
/Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python/recap.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/Users/paulpatterson/Documents/Python/recap.py: line 3: `start_num = int(raw_input("What number do you wish to start counting at?"))'

So suggests lots of errors, but file runs perfectly if I run it from  paulpatterson

Comment: @Paul Patterson, try replacing "/user/bin/env" with "/bin/env"

Answer (score 1):

Type in:

```
which python
```

into terminal and that should get you the path to python. Put that on top of your script as others have suggested:

```
#! /path/to/python
```

Also make sure it is executable (the whole chmod stuff). You can check this by typing:

```
ls -l
```

The file should then have something like -rwx-r--r-- next to it. The x means it is executable.

Comment: You can avoid the `which` by having `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: Thanks. Done all this but still not working. 'which python' gives me 
/usr/bin/python, so the shebang I've put at the top is 

'#!/usr/bin/python', but the error message is the same. Using your ls -l suggestion I get

-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 paulpatterson  staff  327  1 Jul 18:37 recap.py

So that seems to be okay.

Answer (score 1):

The other responders have done a good job with your initial question, but I think you would be very well served to actually learn how to use the command line, as your replies have shown that you're not familiar with it yet. I always recommend [this](http://linuxcommand.org/learning_the_shell.php). It's a fantastic guide that will get you comfortable using it.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, I'm not familiar with it yet. Ironically however my initial question was prompted following my attempts to start learning the command line. I bought the following ebook and was attempting a couple of the things it teaches (Take Control of the Mac Command Line with Terminal). I'll give your suggestion a try also.

Comment: It assumes linux, so there will be some differences, but OSX is still a unix, so it's close enough to get you started, and many of the tools are the same (although it uses a BSD userland rather than GNU). You can also just play around in a vm running linux or on a livecd, or whatever other method

Answer (score 0):

Try typing:

```
which env
```

to find out what the path of env is on your system. Change the shebang path to match the full path of the env command found by using the which command.
If that fails. It means you either don't have env installed or env is installed in a system path. Try specifying the full path to the python executable instead of using env by typing:

```
which python
```

And using the full path return in place of the /path/to/env python shebang. The first line of your recap.py should look something like this:

```
#!/path/to/python
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how useful this is to you now seeing as it is a few years later, but I've been struggling with a very similar issue for a good hour now. I am using the Python IDLE to save my code as a .py file. When I was trying to run it in terminal I kept getting a syntax error in the first line. My first line of code was

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

but the interpreter was reading my first line as the IDLE's shell description "(Python w.7.5 (v2.75:ab05e7dd2788... etc, etc.)". What I had to do was delete all of these lines, including the first `>>>` in order for terminal to open my file. So I deleted all the crap the IDLE places as its first lines and voilà! It worked. Here's how I got it to work once in the terminal:

```
cd /directory/where/you/have/your/file
chmod +x filename.py
python filename.py
```

That's it!